# change opacity on hover div using jquery

Tags: jquery, hover, opacity

I have dynamic comment list :

```
<div class="comment">
  <div class="commentact">
    Test1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comment">
  <div class="commentact">
    Test2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comment">
  <div class="commentact">
    Test3
  </div>
</div>​
```

now i need to when user hover each `div` `class='comment'` show `div` `class='commentact'` with `opacity 0` .

i have this jquery function : (I set div commentact default to opacity 0.2)

```
$(".commentact").css('opacity','0.2');

$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".comment").hover(function() {
      $(".commentact").stop().animate({ opacity: 1 });
   }, function() {
      $(".commentact").stop().animate({ opacity: 0.2 }); 
   });

});​
```

Now when i hover `comment div` show all `commentact div` with opacity 0, what's problem! how to fix this? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BBKING/ZLX3L/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLX3L/124/)

`.commentact` is a **child** element, so use: `$(this).find(".commentact")`
 or `$(".commentact", this)`

```
$(function(){ // DOM ready

    $(".commentact").fadeTo(0, 0.2); // initial opacity

    $(".comment").hover(function( e ) {
       $(".commentact", this).stop().fadeTo(300, e.type=="mouseenter"? 1 : 0.2 );
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of `$(".commentact")` use `$(this).find(".commentact")`:

```
$(".commentact").css('opacity','0.2');
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".comment").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).find(".commentact").stop().animate({ opacity: 1 });
    },
    function() {
      $(this).find(".commentact").stop().animate({ opacity: 0.2 }); 
    });
});​
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/ZLX3L/2/